# get execution time only from the command gtime

Tags: macos, shell, time, optimathsat

I need to execute a command and get the execution time of it. I am using gtime but the output is a bit different from what I want.

gtime returns the result of the execution and then the execution time. I need to store the output of the command(which I need it to be the time only) in a variable and use it afterward.
Is there a way to change the command to get the execution time only?

So if I write the command below:

```
executiontime=$(gtime -f "%U" /Users/Desktop/SemanticLocality/optimathsat-1.6.2-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2)
echo "$executiontime"
```

then this is an example of the output I get:

```
sat

(objectives
 (misses_80 1)
)
9.94
```

Comment: Please provide the input and the desired output.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I edited My question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get executable time only from the output you can modify your command on such way:

```
executiontime=$(gtime -f "%U" /Users/ouafaelachhab/Desktop/SemanticLocality/optimathsat-1.6.2-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2|tail -1)
```

Comment: I edited the answer both the path and added part of the command, **-1** gave a strange answer that ended with a **)** for some reason, **-0** returned the time only nothing more.